# Error: Missing newline before EOF - inserted

Tags: c, newlines

In my application I am inserting some files in main file. In that there is common header file to all the code files `(*.c)`. This giving me error:

```
D:\New folder\COM_Port_Cont\COM_Port_Task.h(268) : Error 1 : missing newline before EOF - inserted
D:\New folder\COM_Port_Cont\COM_Port_Task.c(48) : Error 2 : missing newline before EOF - inserted
D:\New folder\COM_Port_Cont\Hdw_Ecg_1X5.c(129) : Error 3 : missing newline before EOF - inserted
D:\New folder\COM_Port_Cont\Timer_Wdg_1XX.c(39) : Error 4 : missing newline before EOF - inserted
D:\New folder\COM_Port_Cont\Main_Prj_Rfid.c: 0 warnings, 4 errors.
```

In this `COM_Port_Task.h` is the common header file.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a newline character at the end of the last line of your `*.h` files.

According to the ANSI standard the `#include` of a file at the beginning inserts the file exactly as it is to the front of the file and does not insert the new line after the `#include` after the contents of the file.

So if you include a file with no newline at the end to the parser it will be viewed as if the last line of `foo.h` is on the same line as the first line of `foo.c`.

For more info:

- [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271/no-newline-at-end-of-file-compiler-warning)
- [example for the curious](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-07/msg01120.html)

Comment: Will you more elaborate on SO to find the solution for this error.

Comment: Just edit your `COM_Port_Task.h` file and add a new (empty) line at the end of the file.